# Java can only display 1 image on JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, jframe

I am trying to display two different images on my screen. one of which is a banner that goes at the top of my `JFrame`, and another that I just placed randomly below the banner for testing purposes. The issue I am having is that while I can display a single image on the screen by adding an object of class `WindowStructure` to my window, I am not able to display more than one image at a time. Only the last image added to the window is displayed on the screen:

Here is the window class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window(String name) {
    super(name);
    setSize(1200, 700);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    WindowStructure banner = new WindowStructure("Beatles Logo.jpg", 0, 0, getWidth(), 75);
    WindowStructure fireball = new WindowStructure("fireball.png", 100, 100, 100, 100);
    add(banner); //banner
    add(fireball);

    setVisible(true);

    while(true){
        repaint();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g

) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
    }
}
```

Here's the actual class that creates the image:

```
public class WindowStructure extends JPanel {
    ImageIcon imageIcon;
    int xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize;

    public WindowStructure(String bannerImg, int xLoc, int yLoc, int xSize, int ySize){
        URL bannerImgURL = getClass().getResource(bannerImg);
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bannerImgURL);
        this.xLoc = xLoc;
        this.yLoc = yLoc;
        this.xSize = xSize;
        this.ySize = ySize;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add constraints. `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default, so `add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH)` to get your banner at the top. Gotta add constraints to both of them. Might wanna look into layouts

Comment: Get rid of the "repaint" loop. Also God rid of the paint method in the frame, this is screwing with how the paint chain works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default layout manager for JFrame is [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). 
As the documentation says: "BorderLayout interprets the absence of a string specification the same as the constant CENTER". For instance:

```
add(banner);  // Same as p.add(banner, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
add(fireball);  // Same as p.add(fireball, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You can fix this if you specify the location as a second argument to add():

```
add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(fireball, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Or you can use another layout manager for the JFrame by invoking setLayout(LayoutManager) in your Window class constructor.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window(String name) {
    super(name);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // or another the layout that best fit your needs...
    ...
```

Guide about layout managers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

The [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) javadocs state that the default layout manager used is [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). To add multiple components, you have to specify a different place in the layout to put each one (`NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, `WEST`, `CENTER`). By default it's `BorderLayout.CENTER` if not specified, which is why you only see the last one added.