# JPanel Smaller than JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I never actually create a `JPanel`, but I seem to be having issues with it inside of my `JFrame`. my "fball" object goes off the screen at random parts and I cannot figure out why for the life of me. I don't actually create a `JPanel` and use the methods to set it up, and dont know how to do that since my class that extends `JPanel` only creates an image. If you help me I will love you forever. (I apologize for my lacking of knowledge in java)

Here is the code for my Window Class:

```
    package game.thirdTry;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static Window instance;
    public static Window getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Window("Game");
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private Window(String name) {
        super(name);
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        addKeyListener(new UserInput());

        WindowStructure banner = new WindowStructure("Beatles Logo.jpg", 0, 0, getWidth(), 75);
        //WindowStructure fball = new WindowStructure("fireball.100x100.png", 100, 100, 100, 100);

        WindowStructure fball = WindowStructure.getInstanceF();

        System.out.println("Fball.xSize: " + fball.xSize + ", Fball.ySize: " + fball.ySize);
        System.out.println("Fball.xLoc: " + fball.xLoc + ", Fball.yLoc: " + fball.yLoc);
        banner.setBounds(banner.xLoc, banner.yLoc, banner.xSize, banner.ySize);
        fball.setBounds(fball.xLoc, fball.yLoc, fball.xLoc + fball.xSize, fball.ySize + fball.ySize);

        add(fball, null);
        add(banner, null);

        setVisible(true);

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Fball.xLoc: " + fball.xLoc + ", Fball.yLoc: " + fball.yLoc);
            repaint();
            try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
/*
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
    }
*/
}

Image Creation Classs (extends JPanel):

    package game.thirdTry;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.net.URL;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class WindowStructure extends JPanel {

    private static WindowStructure fball;

    public static WindowStructure getInstanceF(){
        if(fball == null){
            fball = new WindowStructure("fireball.100x100.png", 300, 100, 100, 100);
        }
        return fball;
    }
    ImageIcon imageIcon;
    int xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize;

    public WindowStructure(String bannerImg, int xLoc, int yLoc, int xSize, int ySize){
        URL bannerImgURL = getClass().getResource(bannerImg);
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bannerImgURL);
        this.xLoc = xLoc;
        this.yLoc = yLoc;
        this.xSize = xSize;
        this.ySize = ySize;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize, null);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" answer when your questions are answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972496/java-can-only-display-1-image-on-jframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my "fball" object goes off the screen at random parts and I cannot figure out why for the life of me

```
fball.setBounds(fball.xLoc, fball.yLoc, fball.xLoc + fball.xSize, fball.ySize + fball.ySize);
```

Why are you setting the "fball" width to be (location + size) and height to be (size + size)? You don't do this for the "banner"

Comment: the banner object never moves, therefore i never had an issue that would make me need to set its bouds. the fball does, and therefore the bounds are the (location, location + dimensions)

Comment: wait, youre right. I fixed it and now that problem is solved. New Problem: only the last object that I gave the "setBounds" to renders and shows up

Comment: @nicknicknick111, panels are opaque so you the last panel added will point over top of the first panel. You need to use the `setOpaque(...)` method, to make the panel opaque. Don't forget to `accept` answers that solve your problem, both in this posting and other postings (as I have already commented above).

Comment: @nicknicknick111, There is a "checkmark" you can click beside the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you move the ball, but the basic problem is probably, that you use the size of the frame instead of the one of the contentpane of the frame. The size of a frame includes the bar on top of the frame (with the minimizebutton, the titles, etc.) aswell.

Comment: how would i go about using the contentpane

Comment: JFrame.getContentPane() returns the contentpane of a frame